# Momentjs parsing wildcard character

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In `momentjs` is there a way to accept a wildcard while strictly parsing an input?

Strictly parse input by passing `true` as the third parameter.

I'd like to accomodate `DD/MM/YYYY` `DD-MM-YYYY` `DD.MM.YYYY` `DD MM YYYY`.
I can add them all in an array, but I'd prefer to use `*` or `.` so I don't have to maintain the list. Is it possible to strictly require date format while ignoring delimiter?

```
moment('12/12/2012', ["DD/MM/YYYY", "DD-MM-YYYY", "DD.MM.YYYY", "DD MM YYYY"], true).isValid() === true;

// ideally ignore delimiter type, this evaluates to false
moment('12/12/2012', "DD*MM*YYYY", true).isValid() === false;
```

Comment: Please share you code...

Comment: @ParthRaval that is the code. `moment('12/12/2012', ["DD/MM/YYYY", "DD-MM-YYYY", "DD.MM.YYYY", "DD MM YYYY"], true).isValid()`. Is it possible to parse a wildcard `moment('12/12/2012', "DD*MM*YYYY", true).isValid()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Strict** parsing is logically the opposite of wildcard. As an example, you probably want to reject `'01/01-2020'`.

That's specifically what the variant you're using is for (strict multi-format).

For non-strict cases the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is fairly clear:

> The parser ignores non-alphanumeric characters, so both of the following will return the same thing.

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
moment("12/25/1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Comment: You're right this does solve delimiter options for DD/MM/YYYY. But if you're trying to validate a more particular format like credit card expiry MM/YYYY. A user can enter a full date and its sill valid `moment('12/12/2012', 'MM/YYYY').isValid()` worse than that any string that somewhat looks like a date is parsed `moment('asdfsf12/12/2012adsfsadfdsf233', 'MM/YYYY').isValid()`

Comment: @Lex - you're right, and non-strict is an inferior option. Other than that though, as I answered, you can't get any flexibility for strict parsing as that is the defining quality of strictness.